# optimized method to search a large text file in iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, file, search

I need to search string in a large text file (approx. 12 to 15 mb file size) on iPhone.

I'm able to search string but the time taken to search is quite long like 10 to 12 mins which is not good.

Any optimized method to solve this issue ?

Comment: What method are you currently using?

Comment: splitting the file contents into array and then iterate over the lines to search the content

Comment: I know this is an old question, but splitting a 12-15mb file into an array is a very expensive process (both computationally and in terms of space). It will be better to read the data into a buffer and scan that. Also, make sure you benchmark this process using an optimized release build, rather than a debug build, as this is the sort of thing that will generally have a huge performance penalty in an unoptimized build.